# How do I know if my experiemental is within 95% matching of my simulation?

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

[image: DataSet]I have two datasets, one experimental the other a simulation. The problem that I am having is that the experimental only has about 700 obs while the simulation has about 30000 (software generated). It has been eight years since my last stats class and I don't remember alot of the particulars but I know that student t is for normal distribution and Mann-Whitney (wilcoxon) is for non parametric. I ran a box plot [image]and then the two tests. But I really am not sure how to interpret the results. The t-test gives this result: Welch Two Sample t-test

data: DS_ks_test and Pulserfile_ks_test t = -25.909, df = 1117.4, p-value < 2.2e-16 alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 95 percent confidence interval: -12057.75 -10360.05 sample estimates: mean of x mean of y -15455.722 -4246.824

My question that I have to answers is if my experimental is at a minimum of 95% of the simulation. I thought the confidence interval set to 0.95 would do that.

Comment: You probably don't need a hypothesis test, but a value to describe the quality of the simulation. Thus you are probably looking for an $R^2$ value. If I am right check out "R squared" or "Goodness of fit" in google.

Comment: Could you explain "my experimental is at a minimum of 95% of the simulation" in statistical terms?

Comment: @ Semoi I thought Chi squares goodness of fit was for discrete vars.  the data sets  are continuous  as the voltage can take any value.

Comment: @user158565 What I mean, is that the requirement for this experiment to give desired results is that the simulation and the experimental need to match within 95%.  For example if every data point for the expermental were at 100 for the simulation the experimental should be 95 volts or 105 volts. for +/- 5% difference

Comment: I give up. Still cannot understand.

Comment: Just to clear things up: Do you mean to say: Given the empirical (informally speaking the data-derived) distribution of my experimental data, do 95% of my simulated data fall within 5% of the values expected by the empirical distribution?

Comment: @ usεr11852- Yes that is exactly what I am saying.